# How to hide an iframe url in HTML source code

Tags: php, html

How to hide an iframe url in HTML source code.I have two applications one applications get an url of another application into its iFrame,so that it displays in its source code.I dont want to display another application url in the source code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you would need to set the IFRAME URL via JavaScript.  The Javascript could then be Obfuscated, so that the URL would not be in plain text...  Please see the following link for the obfuscator:

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

i.e. if it was jQuery...

```
$("#myiFrame").attr('src','http://www.google.com');
```

becomes:

```
var _0xc1cb=["\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x23\x6D\x79\x69\x46\x72\x61\x6D\x65"];$(_0xc1cb[3])[_0xc1cb[2]](_0xc1cb[0],_0xc1cb[1]);
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but it would be possible to figure out where the link eventually goes using something like FireBug or the developer tools that ship with many browsers.  

Do the obfuscation, but also consider making the 'secret' link require a special key that only functions within the session or only for the user, etc.

Comment: Right. The problem with this sort of obfuscation is that anyone even reasonably determined should be able to crack it. However, it is an extra step, if JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it per say, but you can run it through something like [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com/) so that anyone interested would need to go an extra step. Anyway, that's the only thing I can think of. However, if you are displaying that page in a frame, what's the harm in having the URL in the source code? There really isn't a good, foolproof way to prevent someone determined from finding out the location of that iframe page.

Comment: I've run across some software which may require an access token in the url which should be kept server side due to security concerns.

Comment: You can display some link on a secure page, that needs authentication, but the iframe you’re displaying doesn’t. So you might not want to let the link public available, like outside your site/system/app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a php script which uses curl to call the url through localhost, then use this script as your iframe source.

If you have an issue with relative links and sub-directories, you can put your curl script inside the sub-directory.